# Issue on trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am a novice in trigger. Please excuse me if I made any silly question. I was trying to write a trigger which will update a field value (name) in sol_erp_2014_admission_academic_course_master table with change in sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master table. In below, I have mentioned the structure of both the tables and the trigger which I have written.

**Structure of *sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master* table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'cbcs_major_id',
      `major_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `academic_institute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `academic_department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `specialization_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `code` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `unit` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `no_of_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `max_num_of_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `no_of_sem` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `tot_min_credit` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `tot_max_credit` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `min_sem_pass_prctng` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
      `routine_system` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1->Day System; 2-> Week System',
      `exam_evalution_grade_master_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `date_added` date NOT NULL,
      `date_edited` date NOT NULL,
      `is_deleted` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='MAJOR' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Structure of *sol_erp_2014_admission_academic_course_master* table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sol_erp_2014_admission_academic_course_master` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `academic_institute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `academic_department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now the trigger what I have written:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `erp_adbu`.`sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master_update_before`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master_update_before` BEFORE UPDATE ON `sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE name_var VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE id_var INT;

    SELECT name
    INTO name_var 
    FROM sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master
    WHERE sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master.id = NEW.id;

    UPDATE sol_erp_2014_admission_academic_course_master SET name = name_var WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now I am updating a record from *sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master* table. But the corresponding record of *sol_erp_2014_admission_academic_course_master* table is not updating.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your existing trigger:

1. It should be an AFTER trigger, not a BEFORE trigger
2. You don't need to declare any variables. You can use the NEW.name value in the update.

Try something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `erp_adbu`.`sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master_update_before`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master_update_before` AFTER UPDATE ON `sol_erp_2014_academic_course_master` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE sol_erp_2014_admission_academic_course_master SET name = NEW.name WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```